# How to handle a "Nonetype" error?

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that's supposed to remove duplicate entries. Some people in the data have entered in their name twice because they have two phone numbers, and because the phone number field was not an array, to enter multiple, they entered multiple entries.

My script changes the entries to dictionaries with keys corresponding to the column names and then goes through each of the rows.  There is a master for loop that goes through each row, and then a nested for loop that runs through all the elements for each element, comparing them to detect duplicates. When I hit a duplicate, my code is supposed to compare the phone, email, and websites and then append them to an area if they are unique / don't match.

Here's my code:

```
import csv

# This function takes a tab-delim csv and merges the ones with the same name but different phone / email / websites.
def merge_duplicates(sheet):

    myjson = [] # myjson = list of dictionaries where each dictionary

    with(open("ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt", "rU")) as f:

        sheet = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter="\t")
        for row in sheet:
            myjson.append(row)

        write_file = csv.DictWriter(open('duplicates_deleted.csv','w'), ['name','phone','email','website'], restval='', delimiter = '\t')

        for row in myjson:

            # convert phone, email, and web to lists so that extra can be appended
            row['phone'] = row['phone'].split()
            row['email'] = row['email'].split()
            row['website'] = row['website'].split()
            print row

        for i in len(myjson):

            # if the names match, check to see if phone, em, web match. If any match, append to first row.
            try:
                if myjson[i]['name'] == myjson[i+1]['name']:
                    if myjson[i]['phone'] != myjson[i+1]['phone']:
                        myjson[i]['phone'].append(myjson[i+1]['phone'])
#                     if row['email'] != myjson[rowvalue+1]['email']:
#                         row['email'].append(myjson[rowvalue+1]['email'])
#                     if row['website'] != myjson[rowvalue+1]['website']:
#                         row['website'].append(myjson[rowvalue+1]['website'])
            except IndexError:
                print("We're at the end now") 

            write_file.writerow(row)

merge_duplicates('ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt')
```

So everything's going dandy in my code and then it hits the first duplicate and I get this error:

```
{'website': [], 'phone': [], 'name': 'Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.', 'email': []}
{'website': ['www.got.com'], 'phone': ['111-222-3333'], 'name': 'Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP', 'email': ['cersei@got.com']}
{'website': [], 'phone': [], 'name': 'Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.', 'email': []}
{'website': ['www.daManWithThePlan.com'], 'phone': ['000-000-1111'], 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': ['dman123@gmail.com']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/samuelfinegold/Documents/noodle/delete_duplicates.py", line 40, in <module>
    merge_duplicates('ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt')
  File "/Users/samuelfinegold/Documents/noodle/delete_duplicates.py", line 20, in merge_duplicates
    row['email'] = row['email'].split()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
logout
```

Thanks so much for the help!

---

Ex data if it helps:

```
name    phone   email   website
Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.           
"Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP"   111-222-3333    cersei@got.com  www.got.com
Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.           
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    000-000-1111    dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    111-222-333     dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
D G Bamf M.S.           
Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is, if `row['phone']` is `None`, you cannot split it.

You can do this

```
row['phone'] = row['phone'].split() if row['phone'] else []
row['email'] = row['email'].split() if row['email'] else []
row['website'] = row['website'].split() if row['website'] else []
```

`[]` can be replaced by any default value you want to specify (e.g: `None` or `""`).

A cleaner way would be

```
row['phone'] = row['phone'].split() if row.get('phone') else []
row['email'] = row['email'].split() if row.get('email') else []
row['website'] = row['website'].split() if row.get('website') else []
```

Comment: Just checking to make sure, but I'm not sure that's the error because the output shows that there are entries which don't have a phone number.  But the error does not occur. I've update the post with the data if that helps.

Comment: Your stacktrace clearly shows `row['email'] = row['email'].split()` which means `row['email']` is `None`

Comment: Also `""` and `None` are not the same. So, blank phone number need not necessarily mean it is `None`

Comment: Sorry karthikr, you're right! I was quite confused but now see the distinction after checking what row['phone'] printed out.  Also, I think the .get() would work and that if there's an error I could return '' in the .get() like so: 'row.get('website','')'

Comment: Much simpler, although if you have a lot of empty fields it might be more expensive: `for key in ('phone', 'email', 'website'): row[key] = row.get(key, '').split()`

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use `and` to do this:

```
row['email'] = row.get('email',[]) and row['email'].split()
```

The logic is the same as:

```
if row.get('email'):
    row['email'] = row['email'].split()
```

Although, strictly speaking, this does reassign if the key is missing (or email has already been made into a list), so you might want to do this:

```
# you could also use hasattr(row['email'],'split')
if 'email' in row and isinstance(row['email'],str):
    row['email'] = row['email'].split()
```